# Using the fadeout method with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
$('body').on('click' , function(){
     $('body').append('<div class="ajax-success"><p>Its Done !!!</p></div>').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

My intent was to add the div and then remove it with a fadeout effect using the fadeout() function , now obviously the above code fades out the entire html document.

I have seen a few similar threads of SO, but they are with the fadeIn effect and the solution does't apply , also i checked the documentation and there is no callback function available for the `append()` and `appendTo()` which could have been a posible solution to my problem, so how do i go about fading the `div` that i added using the append() method ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard .. I really think this is not a duplicate , but a unique issue !

Comment: its about using fadeOut with append or appendTo !

Comment: Nope. Answer there perfectly fits and explains why your original code didn't work. It's pointless to ask the same thing 1000 times, for each possible jQuery command out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) as this will return the appended `div` instead of `body`:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    $('<div class="ajax-success"><p>Its Done !!!</p></div>').appendTo( this ).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your target is `body` so that is what fades out. Find a way to target the div you want. One of the easiest ways would be:

```
$('body').append('<div class="ajax-success"><p>Its Done !!!</p></div>')
.find('.ajax-success')
.fadeOut(2000);
```

This presumes there is only one 'ajax-success'-classed element on the page. If more, find a way to make your addition unique.

Comment: Your selector is wrong

Comment: @Robusto nice quotes ... if you don't mind me asking , where r u from ?

Comment: one should use `.find('.ajax-success')`, `.find('>.ajax-success')` or `.children('div.ajax-success')` to fix the code, but the usage of `appendTo` instead of `append` seems me personally better.

Comment: Yeah, a typo, left out the dot in my haste. Thanks for being so understanding.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: My profile gives my location.